# Returning a subset of a map/dictionary in elixir?

Tags: dictionary, elixir, subset

I currently have the following method defined:

```
def create_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %User{}
  |> user_registration_changeset(attrs)
  |> PaperTrail.insert()
end
```

The value returned from this method is as follows:

```
{
  :ok,
  %{
     model: %Udia.Accounts.User{...},
     version: %PaperTrail.Version{...}
   }
}
```

How can I rewrite this chain such that only the model value is returned? I would like to access all of the attributes in `%App.Accounts.User{...}` without further nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe into `Map.fetch!/2` (or `Map.get/2` if you want to return nil if the value is not present):

```
%User{}
|> user_registration_changeset(attrs)
|> PaperTrail.insert()
|> Map.fetch!(:model)
```

Edit: for the new code, if you only want to use pipes, you can do:

```
%User{}
|> user_registration_changeset(attrs)
|> PaperTrail.insert()
|> elem(1)
|> Map.fetch!(:model)
```

but I would also suggest the following pattern matching solution which also checks that the returned value's first element was `:ok` and not something else:

```
{:ok, %{model: model}} =
  %User{}
  |> user_registration_changeset(attrs)
  |> PaperTrail.insert()
model
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my original question. The returned value isn't a map, but `{:ok, %{...}}`. Thank you for your time

Comment: I've added 2 suggestions for that.